# WLAN shows Wifi, but not my personal router SSID

Tags: wireless

Yesterday I installed Ubuntu 14. 04 on my notebook and had many troubles with it.

1. Installed Ubuntu 14. 04 configured everything how I like it (minimal changes) and then enabled in additional drivers new Graphic drivers ("Nvidia binary driver -version 331. 38" (propretiary, tested)). The result was that Ubuntu has been damaged and I could not boot etc. No solution of solving this problem I found on the forums worked for me.
2. I used my previous Clonezilla Image and reinstalled Ubuntu 14. 04. With the opensource drivers everything ok (but it does not run as smooth as it does with the Nvidia drivers).

My notebook was running while I was not near it. When I came back my Notebook was in sleep mode. After I pressed the Power Button it tells me that I am offline (Wi-Fi). When I try to reconnect it shows really all Wi-Fi Routers near me, but not my personal Wi-Fi Router Access. Under "more networks" I can't find it too. When I go to Dash and search for Network there is a huge list of available Networks, but not my own.
When I switch to an other OS with the same Notebook I can find my Wi-Fi SSID. And I am sure that it will work again when I reinstall Ubuntu again. But this would be the third time and I don't want to reconfigure all again.

So is there a solution for this problem?

Hardware:
Acer Aspire 5742G
Intel i5-450M
Nvidia Geforce GT540M
Wi-Fi: Atheros AR5B97

Comment: Are you sure that your SSID is visible for other devices?

Comment: Hello, yes its visible. On my router configuration I turned it visible. All my other devices (Android, IOS) can see my SSID and connect to it. When I boot to Win7 with my Notebook and search for it I can see it and connect too.

Yesterday my Ubuntu 14.04 was connected to my routers SSID. But after it went to Hibernation the SSID disappeared. Since then im offline and my router is not listed in the network manager of Ubuntu.

Comment: I turned the Router On and Off and now it works again. But I remember that this same problem appeared on Linux Mint. Maybe it has something to do with the drivers, I dont know.

--Solved

Comment: I would report a bug.

Comment: Your own SSID will appear after a while, I have the same issues on 12.04 and 14.04 (two Lenovo's) it seems that somehow Ubuntu thinks it's connected to that SSID and it's in some inconsistent state, after I while I have a "Disconnected from that SSID" notification and a couple of seconds later it's available to connect. Did you fill a bug about this to Ubuntu ?